# How to get requested url for a guzzle async request?

Tags: php, asynchronous, promise, parallel-processing, guzzle

I'm using guzzle in a loop to get an array of promises. This string in the loop:

```
$rpomises[] = $this->client->getAsync($url, $options);
```

Next, I make:

```
$res = collect(Promise\settle($promises)->wait());
```

One of the items from the result is:
[image]

As you can see it's just an array with string field and `GuzzleHttp\Rsr7\Response` object. So how I can get requested URL from this construction?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: ohk and why the URL is needed. Can't you just make the array of your custom incremental keys to get the result ? and you will be assure by that index that which response is from which URL.

Comment: because he wants to know for which url response came, order of orders being requested is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

My uses:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Requests;
```

Extracted function from class:

```
public function getUrlsInParallelRememberingSource($urls,
                                                   $numberThreads = 10)
{

    $client = new Client();


    $responsesModified = [];

    $promises = (function () use ($urls, $client, &$responsesModified)
          {
              foreach ($urls as $url) {

                  yield $client->getAsync($url)->then(function($response) use ($url, &$responsesModified)
                        {

                            $data = [
                               'url' => $url, 
                               'body' => 'res' // pass here whatever you want
                            ];

                            $responsesModified[] = $data;

                            return $response;
                        });
              }
          })();



    $eachPromise = new EachPromise($promises,
          [
       'concurrency' => $numberThreads,
       'fulfilled' => function (Response $response) 
       {

       },
       'rejected' => function ($reason)
       {               
       }
    ]);

    $eachPromise->promise()->wait();


    return $responsesModified;
}
```

This gives follwing result:

[image]

http://i.kagda.ru/5001133750442_01-11-2020-00:34:55_5001.png